# Check if range of cell has values then other cells on same row must have value

Tags: excel, vba

I have below values in excel sheet, i want to put validation, if there is value in `D2:G10000` then columns `A`,`B`,`C`,`H`,`I`,`J` of the same row must have value otherwise throw an error.

[image]

I am able to check if there is value in `D2:G10000` but stuck on checking next part whether columns `A`,`B`,`C`,`H`,`I`,`J` has values or not.

```
Sub Check_and_execute()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CellsEmpty As Boolean
    Dim rownumber As Integer

    CellsEmpty = True

    For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:H10")
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            'Check Cell A2,B2,C2,H2,I2,J2
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If CellsEmpty = True Then
        Exit
    Else
        MsgBox "Not all cells are empty."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conditionally Check If All Cells Are Not Empty

```vb
Sub CheckAndExecute()
    
    Const WS_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const CHECK_COLUMNS As String = "D:G" ' adjacent!
    Const FILLED_COLUMNS As String = "A:C,H:J"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_NAME)
    
    Dim crg As Range
    
    With Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range(CHECK_COLUMNS))
        Set crg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
    End With
    
    Dim fcCount As Long, fAddress As String
    
    With Intersect(ws.Rows(1), ws.Range(FILLED_COLUMNS))
        fcCount = .Cells.Count
        fAddress = .Address
    End With
    
    Dim rrg As Range
    
    For Each rrg In crg.Rows
        If Application.CountA(rrg) > 0 Then
            If Application.CountA(rrg.EntireRow.Range(fAddress)) < fcCount Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next rrg
    
    If Not rrg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Row " & rrg.Row & " is not empty.", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If I get alerts every time I enter a value in Cell `D2:G10000` (if the condition is not met), I would find it very annoying... No need of VBA. You can use conditional formatting to color the cells say "RED" if the condition is not met.

**Formula**

`=IF(COUNTA($D2:$G2)>0,IF(COUNTA($A2:$C2,$H2:$J2)<>6,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)`

**Applied To Range**

`A2:J10000`

**Setup**

[image]

**In Action**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The below code does what you're trying to achieve.

```vb
Sub Check_for_empty()
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet: Set Sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim row as Long

With Sht1
For row = 2 to .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Check columns D:G of a row
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("D" & row & ":G" & row)) > 0 Then
        'Check A,B,C,H,I,J,
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A" & row & ":C" & row)) + WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("H" & row & ":J" & row)) < 5 Then
            Msgbox "Error on row " & row & "!", vbExclamation + vbOkOnly
        End If
    End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Incidentally I think this job would be better achieved with conditional formatting to highlight blank cells that should have a value.